# Sort input is working backwards

Tags: c++

Ok, this was an assignment that I was deducted points due to the fact that the output was displayed backwards. I was supposed to prompt the user for input then display the input in descending order, but I am having an issue with the display. I have two arrays, one year[] to hold the months and one `month[totalMonths]` to hold the user input. When i sort and display the input the `year[]` does not correspond with the months, it is fixed. So for example if the user enters 1 for Jan, 2 for Feb and 3 for Mar, the display would be;
Jan: 3
Feb: 2
Mar: 1

Any ideas on how i can get the months to correspond with the its proper input for the display? Here is the sort and display function:

```
void sortArray(double month[], string year[], int totalMonths)
{
    int temp;
    bool swap;
    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for(int count = 0; count < totalMonths - 1; count++)
        {
            if(month[count] < month[count + 1])
            {
                temp = month[count];
                month[count] = month[count + 1];
                month[count + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while(swap);
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Here are the months rainfall statistics sorted from highest to lowest: " << endl;

    for (int index = 0; index  < totalMonths; index++)
        cout << year[index] << "\t " << setw(5) << month[index] << endl;
}
```

Here is my `string year[]` definition:

```
string year[] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
            "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
```

Comment: I suppost your year array contain somthing like: {"jan", "feb", "mar",...} ? Can you print your year table definition plz

Comment: I just updated my year[] definition in my post.

Comment: this puts the largest element at top; when you swap you should swap both the month and year (and whatever other fields you have tied together)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you allowed to rearrange the `year` array? In your sort routine, where you swap the `month` values, you can swap the corresponding values in the `year` array.

If you don't want to mutate the `year` array you can just add a level of indirection. Define an array of indices into the `month` and `year` arrays and sort the indices.

```
int index[12] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 };

// inside your sort routine...

if(month[index[count]] < month[index[count + 1]])
{
    temp = index[count];
    index[count] = index[count + 1];
    index[count + 1] = temp;
    swap = true;
}

// print the arrays...

for (int count = 0; count  < totalMonths; count++)
    cout << year[index[count]] << "\t " << setw(5) << month[index[count]] << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfect. Thanks to everyone for your time and help, it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Like [Blastfurnace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445976/blastfurnace) pointed out you have to sort your year array to match the month.
Or if you can't, you can create a small struct to represent your month data. Like this:

```
typedef struct _monthData{
   double data;
   int monthIndex;
} monthData;

void sortArray(monthData month[], string year[], int totalMonths)
{
    int temp;
    bool swap;
    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for(int count = 0; count < totalMonths - 1; count++)
        {
            if(month[count].data < month[count + 1].data)
            {
                temp = month[count];
                month[count] = month[count + 1];
                month[count + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while(swap);
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Here are the months rainfall statistics sorted from highest to lowest: " << endl;

    for (int index = 0; index  < totalMonths; index++)
        cout << year[month[index].monthIndex] << "\t " << setw(5) << month[index] << endl;
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Only thing you have to change    `month[count] < month[count + 1])` to `month[count] > month[count + 1])`. So your complete code will be given below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;

void sortArray(double month[], string year[], int totalMonths)
{
    int temp;
    bool swap;
    do
    {
        swap = false;
        for(int count = 0; count < totalMonths - 1; count++)
        {
            if(month[count] > month[count + 1])
            {
                temp = month[count];
                month[count] = month[count + 1];
                month[count + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while(swap);
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Here are the months rainfall statistics sorted from highest to lowest: " << endl;

    for (int index = 0; index  < totalMonths; index++)
        cout << year[index] << "\t " << setw(5) << month[index] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    string year[] = {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
            "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
    double month[] = {12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};
    sortArray(month,year,12);
    return 0;
}
```